# How to make dropdown in Repeater display different values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, repeater

I have a table that has rows added by the user pressing a button.  In this table there is a dropdown list that displays to values.  My issue is that selecting something on one dropdown changes all of them. Can someone explain what I'm doing incorrectly?

.HTML Code

```
<button ng-show="showAddChoice(choice)" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add Entry</button>

<tbody data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
  <tr>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="Account Name" ng-model="item.AccountName" style="width:104px;"></td>
      <td><select ng-model="type.value" ng-options="v for v in type.values" style="width:80px"></select></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

.JS FILE

```
 $scope.type = {
        "type": "select",
        "name": "Cash",
        "value": "Cash",
        "values": ["Cash", "Securities"]
    };

$scope.choices = [{ id: 'choice1' }];

    $scope.addNewChoice = function () {
        var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
        $scope.choices.push({ 'id': 'choice' + newItemNo });
    };

    $scope.showAddChoice = function (choice) {
        return choice.id === $scope.choices[$scope.choices.length - 1].id;
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have assigned the same ng-model to select in loop. All will point same variable.`ng-model="type.value"`

Instead of this binding same value to all, you can use `choise.type_value` as an example. This will store value of each choise in its own variable.

Comment: This is perfect.  Thanks